# nearest shrunken centroids with sample weights

Tags: r

I am trying to train my data with nearest shrunken centroid classifier using `pamr.train()` function in `pamr` package of `R`. However, I also have a vector including sample weights except the training data. Is there any way to use this function with considering these sample weights?

Or, is there a way to obtain the source code of this function. If so, I can write the codes for weighted mean and weighted variances instead of the unweighted ones.

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried `>?pamr.train()` for help? Also you can call `>pamr.train` to view the source code for the function

Comment: Yes, the actual problem was the nsc function in the source code that I could not find in that package or other packages in R. It worked with pamr:::nsc

Comment: You could also use the `glmnet` package to train an elastic net classifier, which has built-in support for weighting observations differently. With `family="bionomial"` and `alpha=1` you get a linear classifier with L1 penalty similar to `pamr`, although I cannot promise they're identical.